# Gitolite hooks not propagating

Tags: hook, githooks, gitolite

I've been through the extensive gitolite documentation over and over again. This is my configuration :

Git user running gitolite, while I installed Gitolite as another user, which had root privileges. I installed using the gl-system-install method.

Now, I see two copies of hooks/common directory `/usr/local/share/gitolite/hooks/common` and `/home/git/.gitolite/` (and I intend to work with the first one for system wide implementation)

The gitolite-source is located at `/home/user/gitolite-source`

I've put in some dummy hooks in the `/home/user/gitolite-source/hooks/common/` directory (post-udpate, post-update.secondary, post-receive and post-commit). All of these have exec bit set.

If I edit the update hook in this directory and re-run the setup again, the newer update hook (in existing repos) is sym-linked to the update hook in `/usr/local/share/gitolite/hooks/common`.

But even though any newer hooks in the source/hooks/common directory are copied over to both the hook locations, newer sym-links do not appear in my existing repos.

In short : gitolite copies its own hooks, but neglects mine.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer on my own.

I was re-running the gl-system-setup over and over again in hopes of making those sym links created for me under each repository, while it was the gl-setup that did it.

But re-running gl-setup did not work either. (It gave strange parse errors). So I decided to just remove all the gitolite-hooked sentinel files, and push an update to the gitolite-admin repo, which copies hooks over if it does not find the gitolite-hooked file.